# Folder structure of Wheezy help

Tags: linux, raspbian-wheezy

I'm running Wheezy and connecting via SSH, and would like pointing in the direction of a document / tutorial to understand the folder structure; eg where the sys logs are etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is essentially a Debian File Structure, see [FilesystemHierarchyStandard](https://wiki.debian.org/FilesystemHierarchyStandard) for further informations.